# unable to check if <li> is present inside another <li> using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list items as below and i want to hide the children of any list item which had another list inside. If i click on list one, two, three,.. they should toggle, but if i click on 1.1,1.2  they should not be toggled because there is no list present inside 1.1,1.2,...

```
<ul>
    <li class="curchange">one
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="curchange">two
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="curchange">three
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="curchange">four
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">4.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="curchange">five
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">5.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Below is my code but if i click on 1.1, 1.2 still it is hiding them

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("li").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        //hide it's children
        var curEle = $(this);

        if (curEle.has("li")) curEle.children().toggle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<li class="curchange">one
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1.3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

If you don't want the child li's to trigger the function, you need to specify the class `curchange` in the selector before .click()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.curchange").click(function(e){
        $(this).children("ul").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if(curEle.has("li"))
  curEle.children().toggle();
});
```

try

```
curEle.has("li").children().toggle();
```

As `.has` returns a filtered set of objects.

http://api.jquery.com/has/

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/ae4bd.php#

```
curEle.has("li").children().toggle()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li > li").toggle();
```

this might work